# Returning a reference/lvalue

Tags: c++, return-type, assignment-operator, lvalue

I cannot make sense of the following:

Suppose I am creating an overloaded assignment operator. The function would be something like this:

```
MyObject& MyObject::operator=(const &rhs)
{
   // code to make this work

   return *this;
}
```

If 'this' is already a reference, why do I need to dereference it? Why do I need to return the object and not a reference to an object, as indicated by the return type? In other words, why not just do this:

```
MyObject& MyObject::operator=(const &rhs)
{
    // code to make this work

    return this;
}
```

Alternatively, why not this, too:

```
MyObject MyObject::operator=(const &rhs)
{
     // code to make this work

     return *this;
}
```

I am very confused.

Answer (score 3):

> If 'this' is already a reference,

Unfortunately, `this` is *not* already a reference. It is a *pointer* to the object on which the member function was invoked.

It is customary, though by no means necessary, to return a reference to the current object from assignment so as to mimic the behaviour of the built-in assignment operator, but you can return whatever you like.

Comment: You might want to add that the standard "concepts" `MoveAssignable` and `CopyAssignable` require the return type to be `T&` and the returned value to be the object being assigned to, so any class which wants to interoperate correctly with the standard library must do what you call "customary."